# Disabling the Maven project builder when importing projects into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, eclipse-plugin

Each time I import a new project into eclipse I do the follwing:

- Uncheck the "Resolve workspace projects"
- deactivate the maven buider (Project's **Properties -> Builders menu**)

My goal to avoid a full build every time I save the POM or modify a java file and any other builds on dependent projects. I also want to keep my automatic java builder.

In the same way there is a global option to work offline (in **Window -> preferences -> Maven**), is there a way to automatically remove these options every time you import a project ?

Answer (score 0):

You can at least uncheck the advanced "`Resolve Workspace projects`"  option in the "`Import Maven Projects`" Dialog. I am not aware of any possibility to avoid building the project after import without changing global settings (like `Project -> Build Automatically` as suggested by @gOVIL).

Comment: Thank you but that would deactivate all builders, in my case I want to keep the Java builder. I also don't want to have to uncheck the resolve workspace projects every time, for every project.

Comment: @Guillermo Moscoso At least I gave you a solution to prevent resolving workspace projects after the import. And sometimes the answer to a "Is there a way..." question is simply "No." - But let's see what the experts say ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project > Properties > Builders > uncheck Maven Project Builder.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try unchecking

Project -> Build Automatically.

Comment: Thank you as well, see my previous comment/edition. That would work but it would also deactivate my java builder which I need to keep.